# Redirect blob download to local user machine instead app server when downloading google cloud storage file

Tags: python, flask, cloud, storage

My app has capability to download some files from google cloud storage. But when I run the app on my machine it works fine, downloading the file to my machine because in that time my machine is the "server" . When I deploy my python/flask app into cloud server, if user click to download the blob, it is downloaded into server storage, not the user local machine. Any clue about how to do that?

Below my backend download:

```
def download_blob(self, asset_name):
        #receive asset_name from caller function
        if sys.platform == 'win32':
            destination_file_name = 'c:\temp\ddc_data_download.csv'
        else:
            home = os.path.expanduser("~")
            download_folder = os.path.join(home, "Downloads")
            destination_file_name = download_folder+'/ddc_data_download.csv'
            print(destination_file_name)
        source_blob_name = asset_name
        bucket_name = self.get_current_zone(asset_name)

        storage_client = storage.Client()
        bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
        blob = bucket.blob(source_blob_name)
        blob.download_to_filename(destination_file_name)
        return
```